# What does this stacked greater than less than symbol do to this equation

Tags: notation, definition

I'm reading this paper

J. Sohn, N. S. Kim, and W. Sung.
A statistical model-based voice activity detection.
IEEE Signal Processing Lett., 6 (1): 1-3, 1999. doi: 10.1109/97.736233.

and I came across this equation.
$$
\log{\bf\Lambda} = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\log\Lambda_k \mathop{\lessgtr}_{H_0}^{H_1} 
\eta
$$

I've not seen the stacked greater than and less than symbol. What does it mean? How does it affect the equation?

Comment: It's [hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing), $H_0$ and $H_1$ are the null and alternative hypotheses.